# Html5 video, using php variable as source

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

```
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>
<?php
$movie1 = 'movie1.mp4';
echo $movie1;
echo '<center>';
echo '<video width="600" height="300" controls>';
echo '<source src= "$movie1" type="video/mp4">';
echo "Your browser does not support the video tag.";
echo '</video>';
?>
</html>
```

I'm learning php and html now and I was wondering why it can't recognize the variable `$movie1`. The video player only shows blank.

I tried putting the "movie1.mp4" directly as source and it works fine. 
Is there something I'm missing here? thanks in advance

Comment: use `<body></body>` tags and place your code inside there, make sure you've installed a webserver/PHP and access as `http://localhost(orYourHost)/file.php` rather than a probable `c:///file.php`.

Comment: Plus, you've a bad typo here `HMTL`

Comment: you are using single quotes around the entire string, you need to escape the single quotes

Comment: @RamRaider their code works but contains a typo. I tried it. See my comments to the guy. Edit: you're partially right lol my bad.

Comment: the included variable will not work in single quotes unless escaped first

Comment: @RamRaider yeah you're right lol when I viewed my HTML source, it showed the variable rather than the parsed version. Again, *my bad* ;-)

Comment: no problem @Fred-ii- ~ you've managed to put me right several times. Nobody has mentioned the lack of the closing `</center>` tag or lack of body tags though you seem to have nailed it in your answer! :) so +1 from me

Comment: @RamRaider actually I did notice that earlier about the missing `</center>` tag and have made an edit to that effect in my answer a few minutes ago, along with mentioning that it is deprecated/removed. and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an HTML stickler. You have a typo in `HMTL` and should read as `HTML` and you'll get a warning about that.

Then you need to concatenate your variable `"$movie1"` to `"'.$movie1.'"`.

You should use proper HTML markup also, as in adding `<head><title><body>` tags if you're going to learn HTML. You also had a missing closing `</center>` tag, but that won't stop it from working, but should be using a `<div>` to align it with and closing the div.

Here's a rewrite:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$movie1 = 'movie1.mp4';
echo $movie1;
echo '<div align="center">';
echo '<video width="600" height="300" controls>';
echo '<source src= "'.$movie1.'" type="video/mp4">';
echo "Your browser does not support the video tag.";
echo '</video>';
echo '</div>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Plus, make sure you have a web server/PHP installed and accessing it as `http://localhost(orYourHost)/file.php` rather than a probable `c:///file.php`.

A web browser will not parse PHP directives if you're using `c:///file.php` directly into your web browser. You also need to make sure that it is a `.php` extension file. If you're using `.html` as a file extension, then that won't parse the PHP directives unless you instructed your system to treat `.html` files as PHP.

---

**Footnotes:**

The `<center>` tag has been deprecated/removed.

Consult:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

> *"Deprecated
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."*

Comment: I'm sorry for not adding the header,title, this was just testing the html5 video player and I too was lazy to type it :D, truth is I'm planning to make a local streaming site for my home so that I can stream my videos from other devices. I'm using xampp's apache to run the php file. BTW thank you very much really helped me :)

Comment: @TheMaster You're welcome. Thought I'd put in actual syntax to be 100% sure, since there were missing tags etc. Which I've rewritten in another edit using `<div align="center">...</div>`. The `<center>` tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

use double quote to show the `$movie1` var:

```
echo "<source src= \"$movie1\" type=\"video/mp4\">";
```

or `echo '<source src= "' . $movie1 . '" type="video/mp4">';`